# Strange CSS issue with content unit moving to bottom of page in IE - works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Apologies if this is a vague description, I just cannot see how this is happening.

In Chrome and Firefox, [this page](http://www.soundshelter.co.uk/436490/Scuba-DJ_Kicks-K7-Dubstep-K7291LP.html) appears completely fine.

However in IE, the main content (name of record, picture, details etc) moves down to the bottom of the page. I just cannot get my head round why this is happening. Hoping someone can spot the problem.

A slightly strangers problem is this:

In the right content unit (display the smaller images of records), the last record has some of its content "duplicated" onto the next line. This is really strange.

As I said, the page works completely fine in Chrome/FF and these errors only appear in IE.

If you need me to post any code then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is a width problem.(IE looks with another glasses) You can try to reduce the width of release_text or release_image part or increase the total width.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried changing the width of the total, the text, the image and both the left and right menus and it has not changed anything. Any other ideas? Thanks again for your help